# Python 3.4 - 'module' has no attribute 'send_sms'

Tags: python-3.x

For some reason I cannot execute the function of another script even though i imported that module.

The relevant code for 'master_module.py' goes like this:

```
import sms_values

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):  # Class that implements the client threads in this server
    def __init__(self, client_sock):  # Initialize the object, save the socket that this thread will use.
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client = client_sock

    def run(self):  # Thread's main loop. Once this function returns, the thread is finished and dies.
        global QUIT  # Need to declare QUIT as global, since the method can change it

        done = False
        cmd = self.readline()  # Read data from the socket and process it
        while not done:
            if 'quit' == cmd:
                self.writeline('Ok, bye. Server shut down')
                QUIT = True
                done = True
            elif 'bye' == cmd:
                self.writeline('Ok, bye. Thread closed')
                done = True
            elif 'send' == cmd:
                sms_values.send_sms()
                self.writeline('text should be sent')
                done = True
            else:
                self.writeline(self.name)
                cmd = self.readline()

        self.client.close()  # Make sure socket is closed when we're done with it
        return
```

Notes:
The entire code is omitted for clarfication of where the error is
There is no `__name__ == '__main__'` block in `sms_values.py.`
`send_sms()` is not defined inside a class
No indentation on define line, so it's module-level.

Here I'm trying to execute a function from another module in a threaded continuously run server with the conditional 'send' written in user console.

And this is the code i'm running contained in sms_values.py:

```
def send_sms():
    try:
        ss = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        port = 80
        ss.connect((127.0.0.1, port))
        a = url.encode('ascii')  # string needed to change into bytecode
        print(sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % a)
        ss.sendall(a)

        amount_recieved = 0 
        amount_recieved = len(a)
        while amount_recieved < amount_expected:
            data = ss.recv(180)
            amount_recieved += len(data)
            print(sys.stderr, 'closing socket')
            ss.close()
```

Note: The entire code is omitted for clarfication of what function i'm calling.

Fairly straight forward, I just want to send a http POST / GET command to a router when someone types send in the continuous run server.
However traceback flags up this:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py, line 920, in_bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Savag\PycharmProjects\master_module.py", in line 29, in run
    sms_values.send_sms()
AttributeError: 'module object has no attribute 'send_sms'
```

Can anyone please shine some light on this?
I sort of suspect it's because i'm working within a class on another module? I'm not sure if that even matters. Other module/attributeerror answers have either not been answered or don't help this situation.
Now I have imported the other module, `from sub_module import sms_values` also doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you `def send_sms` inside a `if __name__ == '__main__'` block? What do you mean with "i'm working within a class on another module"? Is `send_sms` defined _inside_ a class? If the line with the `def` indented, or is it on module-level?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Nah no, `__name__ == '__main__'` at all in that module. Well if you look in `master_module.py` i'm calling to execute another function, but that code is within a class function. I was wondering if that would cause issues. `send_sms` is not defined inside a class. `def send_sms()` is not indented, does this matter?

Comment: In `sms_values.send_sms()`, is `sms_values` the actual name of the module?

Comment: Yeah, it's exactly that. Except maybe the addition of a `.py`

Answer (score 0):

So yet again i've answered my own question. All that needed to happen was that the module needed to be stored to a value.
Adding:

`z = sms_values`

then `z.sendsms()` in the `elif 'send' = cmd:` loop, worked.